# Proper switch caseonclicklistener with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I can't seems to get my onclicklistener switch case to work. 
Here is a code

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelfirst, container, false);
        ImageView homeb = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.homeb);
        TextView one = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.one);
        TextView two = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.two);

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(view.getId() == R.id.one){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"its working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
```

Setting onclicklistener on single item works fine, but from some reason it won't detect it. I've tried to use the switch case approach but it won't return anything. However it detects the onclicklistener itself whenerver I try to log the rootview childs clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Proper switch case override onClick by implementing  `OnClickListener`, use your switch case there like below

```
 public class Fragment_treasures extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_treasures, container, false);

                Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.StartButton:

                    ...

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement the View.OnClickListner and over ride its method and put your switch inside it.
For example:

```
public class Fragment_treasures extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_treasures, container, false);

                Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.StartButton:

                    ...

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```